# What is the fastest way to calculate the weighted sum of matrix elements?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am currently a bit astonished that this takes so long. I want to calculate the sum of matrix elements, weighted by their distance to the diagonal. The square matrix contains only non-negative integer elements.

### My code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Calculate a score for a square matrix."""

import random
random.seed(0)


def calculate_score(cm):
    """
    Calculate a score how close big elements of cm are to the diagonal.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> cm = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
    >>> calculate_score(cm)
    32
    """
    score = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(cm):
        for j, el in enumerate(line):
            score += el * abs(i - j)
    return score


def main(n):
    import time
    import numpy as np
    score_calculations = 10**3

    t = 0
    for step in range(score_calculations):
        cm = np.random.randint(0, 150000, size=(n, n))
        t0 = time.time()
        calculate_score(cm)
        t1 = time.time()
        t += (t1 - t0)
    print("{:0.2f} scores / sec".format(score_calculations / t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(369)
```

### Analysis

The current code gives only 32.47 scores / sec. `kernprof -l -v main.py` gives the following result:

I tried to loop over the elements themselves (`range(n)` in the loops), but that decresed the speed to only 20.02 scores / sec.

```
Wrote profile results to main.py.lprof
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 109.124 s
File: main.py
Function: calculate_score at line 9

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     9                                           @profile
    10                                           def calculate_score(cm):
    11                                               """
    12                                               Calculate a score how close big elements of cm are to the diagonal.
    13                                           
    14                                               Examples
    15                                               --------
    16                                               >>> cm = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
    17                                               >>> calculate_score(cm)
    18                                               32
    19                                               """
    20      1000          619      0.6      0.0      score = 0
    21    370000       180693      0.5      0.2      for i, line in enumerate(cm):
    22 136530000     43691655      0.3     40.0          for j, el in enumerate(line):
    23 136161000     65250190      0.5     59.8              score += el * abs(i - j)
    24      1000          386      0.4      0.0      return score
```

I'm not sure if there is anything to make this faster, as the code seems to be quite simple.

Comment: if you want the benefits of numpy, don't write loops

Comment: Mmmmm, shouldn't you avoid looping through numpy arrays? Aren't you better constructing a separate matrix of weights, and finding the dot product?

Comment: for an extra boost, cache the weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using `broadcasting` to compute those `weights` and then using `matrix-multiplication` with `np.tensordot` for those `sum-reductions` -

```
def calculate_score_vectorized(cm):    
    m,n = cm.shape 
    wghts = np.abs(np.arange(n) - np.arange(m)[:,None])
    return np.tensordot(cm,wghts, axes=((0,1),(0,1)))
```

The last step of `sum-reduction` could also be computed with `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij',cm,wghts)
```

Also simply with element-wise multiplication and summation -

```
(cm*wghts).sum()
```

Runtime test -

```
In [104]: n = 369

In [105]: cm = np.random.randint(0, 150000, size=(n, n))

In [106]: calculate_score(cm)
Out[106]: 1257948732168

In [107]: calculate_score_vectorized(cm)
Out[107]: array(1257948732168)

In [108]: %timeit calculate_score(cm)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.4 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit calculate_score_vectorized(cm)
1000 loops, best of 3: 675 µs per loop

In [110]: 31400/675.0
Out[110]: 46.51851851851852
```

**`46x+`** speedup there for the given dataset sizes.

---

As mentioned in the comments, if the shape of input arrays stays the same, we could save the weights `wghts` and re-use them with those `sum-reduction` methods discussed earlier for further boost.

### Complete code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Calculate a score for a square matrix."""

import random
random.seed(0)
import numpy as np


def calculate_score(cm, weights):
    """
    Calculate a score how close big elements of cm are to the diagonal.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> cm = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
    >>> weights = calculate_weight_matrix(3)
    >>> calculate_score(cm, weights)
    32
    """
    return int(np.tensordot(cm, weights, axes=((0, 1), (0, 1))))


def calculate_weight_matrix(n):
    """
    Calculate the weights for each position.

    The weight is the distance to the diagonal.
    """
    weights = np.abs(np.arange(n) - np.arange(n)[:, None])
    return weights


def measure_time(n):
    """Measure the time of calculate_score for n x n matrices."""
    import time
    import numpy as np
    score_calculations = 10**3

    t = 0
    weights = calculate_weight_matrix(n)
    for step in range(score_calculations):
        cm = np.random.randint(0, 150000, size=(n, n))
        t0 = time.time()
        calculate_score(cm, weights)
        t1 = time.time()
        t += (t1 - t0)
    print("{:0.2f} scores / sec".format(score_calculations / t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    measure_time(369)
```

This gives `10044.31 scores / sec - 10381.71 scores / sec` (before: 32.47 scores / sec). That is a **309×** speedup!